# C — warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c

I am a newbie in C programming.
Can anyone help me to explain about the error that I'm getting.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

```
test4.c: In function 'main':
test4.c:65:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Below is my code :

```
#include <webots/robot.h>
#include <webots/distance_sensor.h>
#include <webots/differential_wheels.h>

#define TIME_STEP 64

int main()
{
   wb_robot_init();
   int i;
   WbDeviceTag ps[8];
   char ps_names[8][4] = {"ps0","ps1","ps2","ps3",
      "ps4","ps5","ps6","ps7"};

   for(i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      ps[i]=wb_robot_get_device(ps_names[i]);
      wb_distance_sensor_enable(ps[i], TIME_STEP);
   }

   while(1)
   {
      int delay=wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP);
      if(delay==-1)
         break;

      double ps_values[8];
      for(i=0;i<8;i++)
         ps_values[i]=wb_distance_sensor_get_value(ps[i]);
      //printf("ps0=%d\t", ps_values[0]); 

      double left_speed=500;
      double right_speed=500;

      for(;;)
      {

         if(ps_values[0]>80 || ps_values[1]>80 || ps_values[2]>80)
         {
            left_speed =-500;
            right_speed =500;
         }
         else if(ps_values[5]>80 || ps_values[7]>80 || ps_values[2]>80)
         {
            left_speed =500;
            right_speed =-500;
         }
         else
         {
            left_speed =500;
            right_speed =500;
         }

      }
      wb_differential_wheels_set_speed(left_speed, right_speed);
      wb_robot_cleanup();
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: `return 0;` should be out of `while (1) {...}`.

Comment: One space indentation is rather minimal.  I recommend 4 spaces as a good indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a non-void function that is not returning a value. Your compiler has analyzed that the end of the function can be be reached.

```
if(delay==-1)
    break;
```

So your omission of a return statement is suspect or wrong.

Add a `return 0;` or anything sensible value at the end of the function.

The **main** function is special. It is valid `C` to return no value. But even if it's legal to skip the return the compiler *can* give you a diagnostic message (a.k.a. warning).

You can try to convince your compiler that this is okay with some kind of pragmas or command line arguments. Or you give up and return a value, even if you don't think it's necessary. This will suppress this warning. (One statement is not that expensive.)

Comment: It's `main()`; 0 is a sensible 'success' status.  It can also be spelled EXIT_SUCCESS (defined in `<stdlib.h>`.  EXIT_FAILURE is an alternative standardized value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the `return` statement you have at the end of your `while` loop was placed there by mistake. Otherwise, the function will return after one round of execution of the code inside the loop. What's the point of the loop then?

Instead of

```
   while(1)
   {
      int delay=wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP);
      if(delay==-1)
         break;

      ....
      ....

      wb_differential_wheels_set_speed(left_speed, right_speed);
      wb_robot_cleanup();
      return 0;
   }
```

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
   while(1)
   {
      int delay=wb_robot_step(TIME_STEP);
      if(delay==-1)
         break;

      ....
      ....

      wb_differential_wheels_set_speed(left_speed, right_speed);
      wb_robot_cleanup();
   }

   // The return statement outside the while loop.
   return 0;
```

This will fix the compiler warning too.

Comment: I've tried follow your suggestion and it works!! Thank you very much! ^.^